# Different issues in local and server

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sonarqube, sonarlint

In my organization we have a sonarqube server set up and working - there we can see the results on a daily basis. Now we want to introduce sonarlint to see exactly the same state on the local developer PC-s and on the server. I've set up the sonarlint extensions and bind the connection sucessfully. When i change an issue in the server e.g.: to info, the modifications are not getting synchronized to the local PC-s, and i have no idea how to fetch the server state.

Does anybody solved this issue already?

(IDE: VS 2017 Enterprise)